# awk statement within sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have multiple occurrences of the pattern:

```
)0.[0-9][0-9][0-9]:
```

where [0-9] is any digit, in various text context but the pattern is unique as this regex. And I need to turn the decimal fraction into integer (percent values from 0 to 99).

A small example substring would be

`=1:0.00055)0.944:0.02762)0.760:0` to turn into

`=1:0.00055)94:0.02762)76:0`

What I’m doing is :

```
cat file | sed  -e "s/)\([0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]\):/)`echo "\1"|awk '{ r=int(100*$0); if((r>=0)&&(r<=100)){ print r; } else { print "error"; exit(-1); } }'`:/g"
```

but the output is `)0:`

where is the fault?...

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Say, if `)[0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]:` = `)0.123:`  then the output would be  `)12:`

Comment: @Gilles Quenot ... huh...check it bellow?

Comment: Refresh the page & check my response or click https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916887/465183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) *one-liner* command :

```
perl -pe 's/\)(\d+\.\d+):/sprintf ")%d:", $1 * 100/ge' file
```

Before :

```
=1:0.00055)0.944:0.02762)0.760:0
```

After :

```
=1:0.00055)94:0.02762)76:0
```

If you need to replace for real in editing mode, add `-i` switch :

```
perl -i -pe '...'
```

Comment: Right…
But I need to find & replace this pattern in a complex string where it’s surrounded by various other digits.That’s why was trying to pipe awk from within sed. 

Your solution is smart but it won't find and replace within a string.. Thanks in advance for further ideas! )

Comment: So better add real sample input and expected output. Your attempt is not clear

Comment: A small example substring would be `=1:0.00055)0.944:0.02762)0.760:0`  to turn into `=1:0.00055)94:0.02762)76:0`

Comment: Thanks to edit your post with this important information

Comment: added -i switch explanations

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked 'where is the fault' and not 'how to solve the problem':

Your backquoted pipeline `echo ...|awk ...` is executed FIRST, producing a single `0` which is then made part of the `s///` command passed to `sed` and thus substituted everywhere the pattern matches. PS: using the newer (post-Reagan) and more flexible notation for command substitution `$( ... )` instead of backquotes is preferred in all shells except csh family, and especially on Stack where backquotes are special to markdown and troublesome to show in text.

If you want to actually solve the problem, which you didn't describe clearly or completely, some pointers toward a better direction:

Standard sed can't execute a command to generate replacement text; *GNU* sed can with flag `e` but you need to make the whole patternspace the command and fiddle anything else into holdspace, which is tedious. perl can evaluate an expression in the replacement for s, including arithmetic; awk (even gawk) can't do so directly, but you can get the same effect by doing the match and the replace/rebuild as separate steps, depending on the unspecified and unclear details of exactly what you want to do; if you want to keep the rest of the line unchanged, something like:

```
 awk 'match($0,/)0[.][0-9][0-9][0-9]:/){ print substr($0,1,RSTART) (substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)*100) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1) }'
```

But you don't actually need arithmetic here if you're satisified with truncating. Just discard the leading 0. and the last digit and keep the two digits in between:

```
 sed 's/)0[.]\([0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]:/)0.\1:/g'
```

Note `.` in regexp unless escaped or in a charclass (as I did) matches *any* character not just period, which may or may not be a problem since you didn't give the rest of your input.

And PS: negative numbers for process exit status don't work (except IIRC Plan 9). Use small (usually < 128) *positive* status values for errors; most common is to just use 1.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and explaining. I guess the reason is now getting clearer. And thanks for the suggestions, very useful.